# Change gradient color on refresh but keep cursor position element active?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I have the cursor position and gradient working but can't seem to figure out how to make the gradient color change while the cursor position element is still working.

I'm trying to have the gradient color change on each refresh, selecting from an array. Here's what it is now:

http://jsfiddle.net/trktqqh6/3/

```js
$(".gradient").mousemove(function( event ) {
  var w = $(this).width(),
      pct = 360*(+event.pageX)/w,
      bg = "linear-gradient(" + pct + "deg,#4ac1ff,#795bb0)";
      $(".gradient").css("background-image", bg);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gradient {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background: #252525;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#currentVal {
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 240px;
}
#currentVal span {
  color: #ccc;
}
#range {
  width: 180px;
  border: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: #424242;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 32px;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle:hover,
#range .ui-slider-handle:focus {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#range .ui-slider-range {
  background: #4ac1ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: you are changing it on mousemove?? and what is the issue exactly?

Comment: Did you mean to say that you need [this](http://jsfiddle.net/trktqqh6/73/)?

Comment: Yesss @Harry thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple to create. Just have an array of colors, use a random number generation method, pick the colors corresponding to the random number from the array, set it to the gradient and assign it to the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = [
    ["red", "yellow"],
    ["blue", "aqua"],
    ["chocolate", "brown"],
    ["steelblue", "lavender"]
  ];
  var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
  bg = "linear-gradient(180deg," + colors[num][0] + "," + colors[num][1] + ")";
  $(".gradient").css("background-image", bg);

  $(".gradient").mousemove(function(event) {
    var w = $(this).width(),
      pct = 360 * (+event.pageX) / w,
      bg = "linear-gradient(" + pct + "deg," + colors[num][0] + "," + colors[num][1] + ")";
    $(".gradient").css("background-image", bg);
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gradient {
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(270deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #4ac1ff, #795bb0);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background: #252525;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
#currentVal {
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-left: 240px;
}
#currentVal span {
  color: #ccc;
}
#range {
  width: 180px;
  border: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: #424242;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 32px;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px 0 0 -7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#range .ui-slider-handle:hover,
#range .ui-slider-handle:focus {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#range .ui-slider-range {
  background: #4ac1ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gradient"></div>
```